# Sort Multi-Dimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

How do I sort the following array so that the houses are sorted Red, Green and Blue (George: Position 0, Steve: Position [1], and Fred: Position [2])?

```
Array
(
    [catOne] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Opponent] => Steve
                    [House_Colour] => Green
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Opponent] => Fred 
                    [House_Colour] => Blue
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Opponent] => George 
                    [House_Colour] => Red
                )
        )

    [catTwo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Opponent] => Peter 
                    [House Colour] => Green
                )

        )

)
```

I've tried using sort(), asort(), and usort() but nothing does what I need?

**Edit:** The sorting needs to be able to be changed easily. It can be in any order of House colour. The order used is just an example.

Comment: Don't just say usort doesn't do what you need after someone suggests it. It can be used to sort your array by the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need to do, you can use [usort](http://www.php.net/usort):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $sort = array('Red', 'Green', 'Blue');
    if (array_search($a['House_Colour'], $sort) > array_search($b['House_Colour'], $sort)) return 1;
    if (array_search($a['House_Colour'], $sort) < array_search($b['House_Colour'], $sort)) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

If you can leverage on defines instead on relying on strings for the house colors the solutions will be straiforward and more efficient.

You should define the House colors in a static class (to simulate an enumerated type)

```
Class HouseColour {
    const Red = 0;
    const Green = 1;
    const Blue = 2;
}
```

In this case you have to declare an opponent/player

```
 $opponent = array ( 'Opponent'=>'Steve', 'House_Colour'=>HouseColour::Green);
```

If you are non confortable with class and static constants (you should be confortable with them as the benefits are really great) you can resort to a sequence of defines

```
define ('HC_Red',0);
define ('HC_Green', 1);
define ('HC_Blue', 2);
```

an opponent become

```
 $opponent = array ( 'Opponent'=>'Steve', 'House_Colour'=>HC_Green);
```

in both cases the usort function is the same:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['House_Colour'] > $b['House_Colour']) return 1;
    if ($a['House_Colour'] < $b['House_Colour']) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want try [`usort`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). It allows you to sort an array specifying a custom callback function. Since you are not clearly stating by what criteria you want to sort your items I can not really help you with the function. (My guess is reverse alphabetically by `House_Colour` since `Red > Green > Blue` but I am not sure if you do not have another criteria I overlooked.)

This simple comparison function orders entries by the house color in the order you specified and is easy to modify to what you really want. Each color has a rank you can assign your self (you can also easily add new colors), also you can change the order easily by flipping the comparison-operator in the `else if` part.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $colors = Array('RED' => 3, 'GREEN' => 2, 'BLUE' => 1);
    // A is ranked same as B
    if ($colors[$a['House_Colour']] == $colors[$b['House_Colour']]) {
        return 0;
    }
    // A is ranked above B
    else if ($colors[$a['House_Colour']] > $colors[$b['House_Colour']]) {
        return 1;
    }
    // A is ranked below B
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You can see a running example [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aEXIj6).

Comment: I have tried usort, but I had no luck with the logic of the function. The sorting needs to be able to be changed easily. It can be in any order of House colour. The order used is just an example.

Comment: Well `usort` is defiantly the way you want to go, it is the only way you can sort an array with a custom function. If you don't clearly say what the sorting criteria is nobody will be able to tell you the proper way, we are programmers and not mind readers.